# Creating columns with window in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am writing you because I am trying to create two columns:

**data_i**: With the value of the column "precio_actual" of the first spark streaming window

**data_f**: With the last value of the column "precio_actual" of the window,

for example now what I have is the following:

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------+------+------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|localSymbol|                time|precio_actual|    bid|    ask|  high|   low| close|             ventana|   string_real_time|   comienzo_ventana|        fin_ventana|PRUEBA|
+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------+------+------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|    EUR.USD|2021-01-07 16:30:...|          1.0|1.22665|1.22666|1.2345|1.2245|1.2328|[2021-01-07 16:30...|2021-01-07 16:30:00|2021-01-07 16:30:00|2021-01-07 16:30:30|   1.0|
|    EUR.USD|2021-01-07 16:30:...|          3.0|1.22665|1.22666|1.2345|1.2245|1.2328|[2021-01-07 16:30...|2021-01-07 16:30:14|2021-01-07 16:30:00|2021-01-07 16:30:30|   1.0|
|    EUR.USD|2021-01-07 16:30:...|          3.0|1.22665|1.22666|1.2345|1.2245|1.2328|[2021-01-07 16:30...|2021-01-07 16:30:15|2021-01-07 16:30:00|2021-01-07 16:30:30|   3.0|
|    EUR.USD|2021-01-07 16:30:...|          4.0|1.22665|1.22666|1.2345|1.2245|1.2328|[2021-01-07 16:30...|2021-01-07 16:30:16|2021-01-07 16:30:00|2021-01-07 16:30:30|   4.0|
|    EUR.USD|2021-01-07 16:30:...|          2.0|1.22665|1.22666|1.2345|1.2245|1.2328|[2021-01-07 16:30...|2021-01-07 16:30:29|2021-01-07 16:30:00|2021-01-07 16:30:30|   2.0|
+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------+------+------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
```

and what I need is the following

```
+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------+------+------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------+------+
|localSymbol|                time|precio_actual|    bid|    ask|  high|   low| close|             ventana|   string_real_time|   comienzo_ventana|        fin_ventana|data_i|data_f|
+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------+------+------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------+------+
|    EUR.USD|2021-01-07 16:30:...|          1.0|1.22665|1.22666|1.2345|1.2245|1.2328|[2021-01-07 16:30...|2021-01-07 16:30:00|2021-01-07 16:30:00|2021-01-07 16:30:30|   1.0|   2.0|
|    EUR.USD|2021-01-07 16:30:...|          3.0|1.22665|1.22666|1.2345|1.2245|1.2328|[2021-01-07 16:30...|2021-01-07 16:30:14|2021-01-07 16:30:00|2021-01-07 16:30:30|   1.0|   2.0|
|    EUR.USD|2021-01-07 16:30:...|          3.0|1.22665|1.22666|1.2345|1.2245|1.2328|[2021-01-07 16:30...|2021-01-07 16:30:15|2021-01-07 16:30:00|2021-01-07 16:30:30|   1.0|   2.0|
|    EUR.USD|2021-01-07 16:30:...|          4.0|1.22665|1.22666|1.2345|1.2245|1.2328|[2021-01-07 16:30...|2021-01-07 16:30:16|2021-01-07 16:30:00|2021-01-07 16:30:30|   1.0|   2.0|
|    EUR.USD|2021-01-07 16:30:...|          2.0|1.22665|1.22666|1.2345|1.2245|1.2328|[2021-01-07 16:30...|2021-01-07 16:30:29|2021-01-07 16:30:00|2021-01-07 16:30:30|   1.0|   2.0|
+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------+------+------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------+------+
```

My code is the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Paso 1: Creacion de SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Spark IB") \
        .master("local[3]") \
        .config("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true") \
        .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 2) \
        .getOrCreate()

    # Paso 2: Leer un stream del kafka topic
    level_1_data_kafka_df = spark.readStream  \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
        .option("subscribe", "level_1_data_test") \
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
        .load()

    # Paso 3: Definicion de Schema
    level_1_data_schema = StructType([
        StructField("localSymbol", StringType()),
        StructField("time", StringType()),
        StructField("precio_actual", StringType()),
        StructField("bid", StringType()),
        StructField("ask", StringType()),
        StructField("high", StringType()),
        StructField("low", StringType()),
        StructField("close", StringType()),
        ])

    #Paso 4: Extraigo el campo "value" del kafka record
    """
    col("value") el campo "value" viene en formato binario
    .cast("string") Le hacemos un cast a string y ahora lo que tenemos es un string
    from_json sirve para deserializar un string a json, es decir, sirve para pasar de string a json con schema en particular
    .alias es para renombrar el schema, si hago level_1_data_value_df.printSchema() lo puedo ver
    """
    level_1_data_value_df = level_1_data_kafka_df.select(f.from_json(f.col("value").cast("string"), level_1_data_schema).alias("value"))

    # Paso 5: Transformacion de datos y ventana
    level_1_data_value_transform_df = level_1_data_value_df\
        .select(
            "value.*"
        ) \
        .withColumn("ventana", f.window(f.col("time"), "30 seconds")) \
        .withColumn("time", f.to_timestamp(f.col("time")) ) \
        .withColumn("string_real_time",f.col("time")[0:19]) \
        .withColumn("precio_actual", f.col("precio_actual").cast("double"))


    # Paso 6: Queries
    level_1_data_value_window_agg_df = level_1_data_value_transform_df\
        .select (
            f.col("*"),
        )\
        .withColumn("comienzo_ventana",f.col("ventana.start")) \
        .withColumn("fin_ventana", f.col("ventana.end"))  \
        .withColumn("PRUEBA", f.expr("case when comienzo_ventana < fin_ventana then precio_actual else 0 end")) \

    window_query = level_1_data_value_window_agg_df.writeStream \
        .format("console") \
        .outputMode("update") \
        .option("checkpointLocation", "chk-point-dir") \
        .trigger(processingTime="5 seconds") \
        .start()

    window_query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Use Window function with orderBy time and find use first() function to get the first value and similarly for the last value in descending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `first` and `last` over column time

```
df.withColumn("data_i", first("precia_actual").orderBy("time"))
  .withColumn("data_l", last("precia_actual").orderBy("time"))
```

or using select

```
df.select(*,
           first("precia_actual").orderBy("time").alias("data_i"),
           last("precia_actual").orderBy("time").alias("data_l"))
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer me! 

i did: 

`level_1_data_value_window_agg_df = level_1_data_value_transform_df\
        .select (
            f.col('*'),
        )\
        .withColumn('fin_ventana', f.col('ventana.end')) \
        .withColumn('data_l', f.last(f.col('precio_actual')))`

and i have the following error: 

pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: grouping expressions sequence is empty, and 'localSymbol' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '(last(precio_actual) AS data_l)' in windowing function or wrap 'localSymbol' in first() (or first_value)...

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Paso 1: Creacion de SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName('Spark IB') \
        .master('local[3]') \
        .config('spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown', 'true') \
        .config('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', 2) \
        .getOrCreate()

    # Paso 2: Leer un stream del kafka topic
    level_1_data_kafka_df = spark.readStream  \
        .format('kafka') \
        .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'localhost:9092') \
        .option('subscribe', 'level_1_data_test') \
        .option('startingOffsets', 'earliest') \
        .load()

    # Paso 3: Definicion de Schema
    level_1_data_schema = StructType([
        StructField('localSymbol', StringType()),
        StructField('time', StringType()),
        StructField('precio_actual', StringType()),
        StructField('bid', StringType()),
        StructField('ask', StringType()),
        StructField('high', StringType()),
        StructField('low', StringType()),
        StructField('close', StringType()),
        ])

    #Paso 4: Extraigo el campo 'value' del kafka record
    '''
    col('value') el campo 'value' viene en formato binario
    .cast('string') Le hacemos un cast a string y ahora lo que tenemos es un string
    from_json sirve para deserializar un string a json, es decir, sirve para pasar de string a json con schema en particular
    .alias es para renombrar el schema, si hago level_1_data_value_df.printSchema() lo puedo ver
    '''
    level_1_data_value_df = level_1_data_kafka_df.select(f.from_json(f.col('value').cast('string'), level_1_data_schema).alias('value'))

    # Paso 5: Transformacion de datos y ventana
    level_1_data_value_transform_df = level_1_data_value_df\
        .select(
            'value.*'
        ) \
        .withColumn('ventana', f.window(f.col('time'), '30 seconds')) \
        .withColumn('comienzo_ventana', f.col('ventana.start')) \
        .withColumn('fin_ventana', f.col('ventana.end')) \
        .withColumn('time', f.to_timestamp(f.col('time')) ) \
        .withColumn('string_real_time',f.col('time')[0:19]) \
        .withColumn('precio_actual', f.col('precio_actual').cast('double')) \

        # Paso 6: Queries

    level_1_data_value_window_agg_df = level_1_data_value_transform_df \
        .groupBy(
            f.col('localSymbol'),
            f.col('ventana')
        ) \
        .agg(
            f.max(f.col('precio_actual')).alias('precio_max_ventana'),
            f.min(f.col('precio_actual')).alias('precio_min_ventana'),
            f.first(f.col('precio_actual')).alias('precio_ini_ventana'),
            f.last(f.col('precio_actual')).alias('precio_fin_ventana'),
        )

    level_1_data_output_df = level_1_data_value_window_agg_df\
        .select(
            f.col('ventana.start').alias('inicio_ventana'),
            f.col('ventana.end').alias('fin_ventana'),
            f.col('precio_max_ventana'),
            f.col('precio_min_ventana'),
            f.col('precio_ini_ventana'),
            f.col('precio_fin_ventana'),
        )

    window_query = level_1_data_output_df.writeStream \
        .format('console') \
        .outputMode('update') \
        .option('checkpointLocation', 'chk-point-dir') \
        .trigger(processingTime='5 seconds') \
        .start()

    window_query.awaitTermination()
```